# How to get my ViewModel instantiated

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, mvvm

I have an application that works, and now I'm trying to do it with proper MVVM.  As I understand it from many months of reading, the LinqToSQL classes (by VS2013) are my model, as is the SQL Server database that it uses.  The UI is the view, and I am implementing some ObservableCollections as my view model.  So here is the ViewModel:

```
    partial class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    static DataClasses1DataContext _dataDc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    ObservableDocuments _oDoc = new ObservableDocuments(_dataDc);

    public ObservableCollection<Document> oDoc
    {
        get
        {
            return _oDoc;
        }
    }

    public ICommand LoadData
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In the working version, the DataContext and ObservableDocuments lines were in the MainWindow code . . . so I have moved them.  Here is the xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="LINQ_MVVM_1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:LINQ_MVVM_1.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding oDoc.View}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="docIDColumn" Binding="{Binding DocId}" Header="ID" Width="65"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DocumentNumberColumn" Binding="{Binding Number}" Header="Document Number" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="altIDColumn" Binding="{Binding AltID}" Header="Alt" Width="55"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And here is the code for the binding reference object, a ViewableCollection, with a filterable view property:

```
    public class ViewableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private ListCollectionView _View;
    public ListCollectionView View
    {
        get
        {
            if (_View == null)
            {
                _View = new ListCollectionView(this);
            }
            return _View;
        }
    }
}

class ObservableDocuments : ViewableCollection<Document>
{
    public ObservableDocuments(DataClasses1DataContext dataDc)
    {
        foreach (Document doc in dataDc.Documents)
        {
            this.Add(doc);
        }
    }
}
```

Moving the _dataDc and _oDoc into the ViewModel class has resulted in nothing populating the data grid.  What am I doing wrong?  It seems that getting the ViewModel instantiated is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
```

Means that you are still looking at the code-behind for your `DataContext`. In case you aren't aware, the `DataContext` defines the root object to which all bindings look at the start of their "Path".

So you're right, the VM isn't being instantiated because *you never instantiated it*.

Instead, remove that line and in your UI constructor write:

```
DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

There are other ways to do it of course, but thats the simplest.

Comment: @PaulGibson Great! If you have more questions about how `DataContext` and bindings work, swing by the WPF chat room. I'm there most of the time, and if you ping me I'll be sure to get back to you.